# Validate CIDR overlap in Java

Tags: java, validation, cidr

Having two CIDR blocks - how can I validate in *Java* that they are not overlapping? I figured out following solution, but I'm not sure that:

- it's complete,
- it can be done without external library dependency,
- it can be done by more elegant/efficient way.

Following code uses [SubnetUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html).

```java
void isSubnetOverlap(String cidr1, String cidr2) {
    SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo subnetCidr = new SubnetUtils(cidr1).getInfo();
    SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo clusterCidr = new SubnetUtils(cidr2).getInfo();

    if (subnetCidr.isInRange(clusterCidr.getLowAddress())
            || subnetCidr.isInRange(clusterCidr.getHighAddress())
            || clusterCidr.isInRange(subnetCidr.getLowAddress())
            || clusterCidr.isInRange(subnetCidr.getHighAddress())) {

        // e.g. throw some exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to avoid an external library?  Why are you worried about efficiency?

Comment: Less dependencies is corporate stuff - every non-aproved open source library has to go through a painful process.  Speaking efficiency, I mean how to write code in readable, comprehensible and elegant way, rather than performance.

Answer (score 1):

I have written following function to determine network overlap function which returns true if the networks are overlapped

```
public static boolean isNetworkOverlaped(String network1, String network2){
        inet.ipaddr.IPAddressString ipaddress1 = new IPAddressString(network1);
        inet.ipaddr.IPAddressString ipaddress2 = new IPAddressString(network2);

        int ipaddress1Prefix = ipaddress1.getNetworkPrefixLength();
        int ipaddress2Prefix = ipaddress2.getNetworkPrefixLength();

        boolean isOverlapped = false;
        if(ipaddress1Prefix < ipaddress2Prefix){
            IPAddress firstIPAddress = ipaddress2.getAddress().iterator().next();
            isOverlapped = ipaddress1.contains(firstIPAddress.toAddressString());
        }else {
            IPAddress firstIPAddress = ipaddress1.getAddress().iterator().next();
            isOverlapped = ipaddress2.contains(firstIPAddress.toAddressString());
        }

        return isOverlapped;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works; you don't need to check the high addresses.  I wouldn't suggest writing your own solution for something that already works, but checking a network as a subnet of another network isn't hard.

Just use the network mask of the larger network to see if the smaller network is a subset of the larger network.

Here's an example in java...

```java
String[] c1 = s1.split("/");
String[] c2 = s2.split("/");

if (c1.length != 2 || c2.length != 2) {

  throw new Exception("malformed cidr address" + " " + "(s1=" + s1
  + ", " + "s2=" + s2 + ")");
}

String[] a1 = c1[0].split("\\.");
String[] a2 = c2[0].split("\\.");

if (a1.length != 4 || a2.length != 4) {

  throw new Exception("malformed cidr address" + " " + "(s1=" + s1
  + ", " + "s2=" + s2 + ")");
}

int m1, m2;

try {

  m1 = Integer.parseInt(c1[1], 10);
  m2 = Integer.parseInt(c2[1], 10);

} catch (NumberFormatException ne) {

  throw new Exception("malformed cidr address" + " " + "(s1=" + s1
  + ", " + "s2=" + s2 + ")");
}

if ((m1 < 0) || (m1 > 32) || (m2 < 0) || (m2 > 32)) {

  throw new Exception("malformed cidr address" + " " + "(s1=" + s1
  + ", " + "s2=" + s2 + ")");
}

int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

  try {

    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(a1[i], 10);
    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(a2[i], 10);

    if ((x1 < 0) || (x1 > 255) || (x2 < 0) || (x2 > 255)) {

      throw new Exception("malformed cidr address" + " " + "(s1=" + s1
      + ", " + "s2=" + s2 + ")");
    }

    i1 = i1 | (x1 << (24 - (i << 3)));
    i2 = i2 | (x2 << (24 - (i << 3)));

  } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {

    throw new Exception("malformed cidr address" + " " + "(s1=" + s1
    + ", " + "s2=" + s2 + ")");
  }
}

int l1 = (int) (((long)1 << (32 - m1)) - 1);
int l2 = (int) (((long)1 << (32 - m2)) - 1);

i1 = i1 & ~l1;
i2 = i2 & ~l2;

if ((i1 & ~l2) == i2 ||
    (i2 & ~l1) == i1)
  return true;

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do this for you with the code in the above answer or this code here.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

When CIDR blocks overlap, one must contain the other.  There is no partial overlap with CIDR blocks.

```java
static boolean overlaps(String one, String two) {
    IPAddressString addrOne = new IPAddressString(one);
    IPAddressString addrTwo = new IPAddressString(two);
    return addrOne.contains(addrTwo) || addrTwo.contains(addrOne);
}
```